# jQuery ajax responseText 'undefined'

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've got some jQuery which posts two variables to a php script. The PHP is very simple and simply returns a string based on what it's given, i.e. 'update successful' which I'd like to use in some way on the page.

The first time I click I get an alert saying 'undefined', any further clicks and everything works fine. Pretty sure I'm not far off but I can't work out this problem!

I've used firebug and the data is posted and the correct response is received on all attempts.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#updatehol').click(function() {
    additions  = $('#additions').attr('value');
    deductions   = $('#deductions').attr('value');
    datastring = 'additions='+ additions +'&deductions='+ deductions;

    $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: datastring,
                url: "doadjust.php",
                complete: function(data) {
                alert(data.responseText);
                }
               });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Sorted it. Needed `async: false` option in the Ajax function.

```
$.ajax({
    type:     "POST",
    data:     datastring,
    url:      "doadjust.php",
    dataType: "html",
    async:    false,
    success:  function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: If that fixed it, something else must be wrong.  It should only very rarely be necessary to make any AJAX call synchronous.  That's why it's called *A*JAX

Comment: ah - you've changed 'data.responseText' to just 'data'.  That's probably what fixed it, the `data` parameter to `success` has no such field.  Try making it async again.

Comment: Hmm yes I agree it seems strange making it synchronous. I gave it a go using alert(data) and async - back to the same problem as I started out with, seemingly successful posts and responses but no alert until the second click.

Answer (score 1):

What do you get with just an `alert(data)` ??

btw it's success not complete:

```
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: datastring,
                url: "doadjust.php",
                success: function(data) {
                   alert(data);
                }
               });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. With the original code I posted above using alert(data), the alert contains [object Object]. Using success gets rid of the rogue 'undefined' alert however now no alert appears on the first click, but one on the second. Again according to firebug I am making a successful post and receiving a reponse for both clicks.

Comment: Just tried the error callback, no errors from what I could see. My end goal for the response is to use in a similar way to this: $('#resultbox').html("<div id='resultbox'>"+ data +"</div>"); - tried this and the suggestion above, same results as in the alert.

Comment: try to add this option: dataType: "html"

Comment: Just gave that a shot, still getting successful post/reponse each time but an alert only on the second click :o(

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.

```
var min = $.ajax(
        {
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'LineChart.asmx/LineChrt',
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            success: function(data) {
                // alert("SUCESS");
            },
            error: function(xhr, status) {
                alert("hatada:" + xhr.responseXML);
            },
            onComplete: function(data) {

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but I just ran into the same problem and found the answer in the jQuery docs.

responeText and responseXml are only polulated when using dataType: text or xml. If you use any other data types it will be passed as the first param in your success callback.

From the jQuery Docs:

> **Data Types**
>
> The $.ajax() function relies on the server to provide information
>   about the retrieved data. If the server reports the return data as
>   XML, the result can be traversed using normal XML methods or jQuery's
>   selectors. If another type is detected, such as HTML in the example
>   above, the data is treated as text.
>
> Different data handling can be achieved by using the dataType option.
>   Besides plain xml, the dataType can be html, json, jsonp, script, or
>   text.
>
> **The text and xml types return the data with no processing. The data is
>   simply passed on to the success handler, either through the
>   responseText or responseXML property of the jqXHR object,
>   respectively.**

Answer (score 0):

You should add `json` type, ex.:

```
$('#test').on('click', '.testclass', function(event){
    $.post($(this).attr('href'), 
     function(data) {
        alert(data.text);
    }, 'json');
});
```