# Why doesnt this Ajax request work in IE?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following JQuery AJAX request, it works fine in Chrome but when I test in IE, it returns `undefined`:

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=26650603c42f41d78bfb5c5c740747d3&_render=json&_callback=?',
    dataType : 'xml',
    complete : function(data) {
        console.log(data.responseText);
    }
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery ajax responseText 'undefined'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460275/jquery-ajax-responsetext-undefined)

Comment: as stated async: false is required.

Comment: Is this cross-domain AJAX? If so check this out http://forum.jquery.com/topic/cross-domain-ajax-and-ie#14737000000729148

Comment: I tried async : false and it still is undefined. @JosephSzymborski Yeah, its cross domain

Comment: @JosephSzymborski I tried the suggestion in that page and I get `SCRIPT5: Access is denied.`

Comment: @j08691 I tried IE9 but I assume it wont work for lesser versions too.

Comment: why are you using dataType:Xml when the url is returning json? also which version of IE..is it IE7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url : 'http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=26650603c42f41d78bfb5c5c740747d3&_render=json&_callback=pipeCallback', 
        dataType : 'jsonp',
        complete : function(data) {
            //alert(data.responseText);
            //console.log(data.value);
        },
         error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert(error);
            }
    });
});
function pipeCallback(d){
    data = d;
    //console.debug(d);
    var arts = d.value.items;
    for (var i=0; i<arts.length; i++)
    {
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.setAttribute("href", arts[i].link);
    a.innerHTML = "<h1>" + arts[i].title + "</h1>"
    var dv = document.createElement("div");
    dv.innerHTML = arts[i].description;
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    document.body.appendChild(dv);
    }   
}
```

Have just tested it is working fine 
also get rid of **console.log** calls, if the developer tools arenot open it wont work in IE.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it's a matter of browser security settings:

- http://www.webdavsystem.com/ajax/programming/cross_origin_requests
- http://sunh11373.blogspot.ca/2007/04/cross-domain-ajax-in-ie.html
- [Jquery $.ajax fails in IE on cross domain calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362474/jquery-ajax-fails-in-ie-on-cross-domain-calls)

Internet explorer just doesn't allow CORS (at least in -IE7) as a matter of security. IE8+ seems to be able to do XDR, however.