# Is there a way to convert an HTML response to JSONP object or another way to have the success event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to detect the user's city via this website: http://www.ipaddresslocation.org/my-ip-address.php. Almost all of the free geolocation APIs I've seen so far were not very accurate. When the following code executes, I see all the information I need in the Response tab (in the Network tab in Firefox), but the success event fails and I am not able to access any of that data.

```
$(document).ready(function(){                    
   getCity(); 
});

var parameters = {
  "Content-Type": "text/html",
  'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
};

function getCity() {

    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: 'http://www.ipaddresslocation.org/ip-address-locator.php',
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      success: function(data) {
        console.log("success");
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        console.log("ERROR");
        console.log(error.message);
      }
    });
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try implementing a purposed error (like on the url), to see if you go inside the error callback. If you don't, you will know the problem lies there, and you can come back here and answer me.

Comment: Do you mean doing a test to check if the url is broken? When I run this in codepen, the error message gets printed, but I am getting the correct location in the Firefox request window.

Comment: Yes that's what I meant. Can you upload a screenshot with what returns in your Firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with my code was that I was trying to get the server to respond when I just needed to read the HTML page in my browser. Because of the Same Origin policy, I ended up using the CORS Anywhere node.js proxy to add headers to the proxied request and then doing RegEx to get the city. This link is great at explaining how to make cross-domain requests: [Loading cross domain endpoint with jQuery AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005500/loading-cross-domain-html-page-with-jquery-ajax) .

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $.ajaxPrefilter(function(options) {
    if (options.crossDomain && jQuery.support.cors) {
      var http = (window.location.protocol === 'http:' ? 'http:' : 'https:');
      options.url = http + '//cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' + options.url;
    }
  });

  $.get(
    'http://www.ipaddresslocation.org/ip-address-locator.php',
    function(response) {
      //regex to get the desired info
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens when third party APIs haven't set things up developer-friendly. You can use the `complete` callback instead of the `success` callback and then access the `responseText` property of the `XHR` response:

```
$(document).ready(function(){                    
   getCity(); 
});

var parameters = {
  "Content-Type": "text/html",
  'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
};

function getCity() {

    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: 'http://www.ipaddresslocation.org/ip-address-locator.php',
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      complete: function(jqXHR, txtStatus) {
        var myData = jqXHR.responseText;
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        console.log("ERROR");
        console.log(error.message);
      }
    });
}
```

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: It looks like myData is undefined and the error message still gets printed to the console. I have no idea why that is.

Comment: It's just the way the API is returning. Could you do a `console.log(jqXHR);` in the complete callback? That will tell you what properties are available there and where those data are.

Comment: I'm able to see all of its properties. It looks like I cannot retrieve anything from the HTML file shown in the response because this object doesn't have a property to do so. Is that right or am I overlooking something? ( Object { readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: .ajax/v.getResponseHeader(), getAllResponseHeaders: .ajax/v.getAllResponseHeaders(), setRequestHeader: .ajax/v.setRequestHeader(), overrideMimeType: .ajax/v.overrideMimeType(), statusCode: .ajax/v.statusCode(), abort: .ajax/v.abort(), state: .Deferred/d.state(), always: .Deferred/d.always(), then: .Deferred/d.then(), 10 more… }).

Comment: What you see in the response tab should be available in `jqXHR.responseText`. You don't see that as an option?

Comment: Maybe it should by synchronous?  have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5472371/844726

Comment: responseText is not one of the keys. For most of the prop, obj[key] returns "function ()". Check it out codepen.io/veronikabenkeser/pen/qdJrxo . Just tried experimenting with making it synchronous, but nothing has change. I think this "responeText and responseXml are only polulated when using dataType: text or xml. If you use any other data types it will be passed as the first param in your success callback" may be the problem because my callback function fails.